# Ornstein Uhlenbeck velocity with displacement-based drift

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Apologies, I'm not very good at stochastic calculus so I'll ask the below as best I can..!

I have a particle I am trying to model which bounces around the origin, but which has a momentum component.

I'm looking to approximate it with something resembling an Ornstein Uhlenbeck process for velocity $V_t$. I started with the definition from the wiki : en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process, but I have added an additional drift term based on the particle's displacement $S_t$ from the origin:

$dV_t = -(\alpha S_t+ \beta V_t) dt +\sigma dW_t$
where $S_t$ is $\int_0^t{V_s ds}$

For simplicity's sake, assume $S_0=0$ $V_0=0$

Specifically I am interested in the stationary process of $S_t$, which means potentially not all configurations of parameters work - I wish to ignore cases where $\left|S_t\right| \to \infty$

I would like to find out:

1. Necessary / sufficient conditions for $\xi$, $\theta$ such that the stationary process of $S_t$ exists
2. A representation for $\mathrm{Cov}{[{S_{t_1},S_{t_2}}]}$ where $t_1 = t + u$,
   $t_2 = t + v$, $t \to \infty$

Any help that can point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!!

Edit: It would appear this might be the Langevin equation for harmonic motion in a fluid? Can someone confirm if this is correct / if an analytical solution is available for this?

Comment: So I'm just going off the definition of the OU process per the wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process But adding an additional drift based on the displacement. Assume S_0=0 V_0 = 0. Not sure anything else?

Comment: $S_t$ is the displacement of the particle with velocity $V_t$, ie $S_t$ = $\int_0^t{V_t}$

Comment: Apologies, I had that defined but must've accidentally erased it - rectified now. Does the fact it's path-dependent mean it's not easily solvable?

Comment: Sorry I was just being very specific - as I don't know how to describe it correctly. Will remove that